# How can I access a function wrapped into a namespace by brunch without "wrapper: false"?

Tags: javascript, elixir, phoenix-framework, brunch

My brunch-cofnig:

```
npm: {
  enabled: true,
  whitelist: ["jquery"],
  globals: {
    $: "jquery",
    jQuery: "jquery"
  }
}
```

In a simple html **static** web application I can use x-editable very easialy. However, in my web framework (elixir) I have to use brunch for some reason and this code doesn't work anymore:

```
$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = "popup";
$(".editable").editable();
```

because X-editable is wrapped into a function by

```
 require.register("web/static/js/bootstrap-editable.min.js", function(exports, require, module) {
```

and other functions from other js files also.

I've tried different things to access to it to no avail, for example:

```
$(".editable").require("web/static/js/bootstrap-editable.min.js").editable(); 
// note that $ is visible here
```

How can I get it to work without using the flag "wrapper: false" in the brunch config?

The question is about x-editable, but also in general I want to know how deal with this kinds of issues in brunch with others js libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to import/require the library. This will execute the code (in this case register the JQuery plugin) and allow you to use it.

```
import "web/static/js/bootstrap-editable.min.js"
$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = "popup";
$(".editable").editable();
```

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`

Comment: @gazler, what if plugin is in package-config.json, is it still necessary to import it? I'm not sure how it works on Phoenix 1.3 but I essentially have the same problem.